# Python script runs fine from command line, file not found error when using Eclipse and PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse

Folder Structure:

```
src
+ root
+ nested
  ++ myprogram.py
  ++ helper.py
  ++ res
    +++ excluded.txt
    +++ whitelist.txt
```

Case 1 - Create a PyDev project in eclipse. Run as a PyDev configuration. Specify main module and everythin. Main module is myprogram.py. When run using eclipse, I get the error -
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\res\excluded.txt'
excluded.txt is specified as => excluded_words_file = r'.\res\excluded.txt', inside myprogram.py

Case 2. Run the script myprogram.py using command line. Runs perfectly fine.

The only difference is that Eclipse is also using SVN source control for this project. So I tried after disconnecting the project from the repository. But still the same issue.

So what might I be doing wrong in the Eclipse setup? Thanks.

Comment: I think that Eclipse treats `src` as working directory. Try to change file path to `excluded_words_file = r'nested\res\excluded.txt'` and check if it works.

Comment: If you don't want to change the hard coded file path, you could also go into Run/Run Configurations... , select the run configuration for myprogram.py, and change the working directory under the Arguments tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick debug with :

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

should let you see eclipse is not running from the same dir you place yourself when invoking from commandline.

From the python module -> right click -> properties -> run/debug settings -> python run -> arguments, you can change the working directory. 
IMHO is not a good idea, better change the program so it reads from an absolute path, in order to have it work no matter where is deployed.

Comment: Thanks. I debugged using this. And yes, I will change the program to read from an absolute path in my next version.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me a like a path issue. Post what you see when you do

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

OP says that `sys.path` outputs the following

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sumod_pawgi\workspace\SWCTester\src\root\nested 
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.1.0.2011052613\pysrc 
C:\Documents and Settings\sumod_pawgi\workspace\SWCTester\src 
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages 
C:\Python25 
C:\Python25\DLLs 
C:\Python25\lib 
C:\Python25\lib\lib-tk 
C:\Python25\lib\plat-win 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\python25.zip 
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.0.0.2011040403\PySrc 
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\py2exe
```

From what I see, I can identify as a problem: your `res` directory is not in your path. This can be fixed in one of two ways:

1. do `sys.path.append('path/to/res/directory')`
2. add the `res` directory to the path in PyDev Run Configurations

OR

1. Right Click on *.py file (in Eclipse), select 'Run as'-> 'Run Configurations...'
2. On the right hand side, Select 'Arguments' tab.
3. Verify 'Working Directory' section, check selected working directory (all required files should be present in there - if not click on 'workspace' button and select folder from workspace)

Comment: Thanks. This is what my path says - C:\Documents and Settings\sumod_pawgi\workspace\SWCTester\src\root\nested
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.1.0.2011052613\pysrc
C:\Documents and Settings\sumod_pawgi\workspace\SWCTester\src
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages
C:\Python25
C:\Python25\DLLs
C:\Python25\lib
C:\Python25\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python25\lib\plat-win
C:\WINDOWS\system32\python25.zip
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.0.0.2011040403\PySrc
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\py2exe

Comment: If my edit doesn't work, feel free to comment and I will do my best to help